# How to get a byte[] data from an Image object?

Tags: java, java-me, lwuit

I have Image objects created from images stored in the mobile memory. I want to get the byte[] value of these Image objects. How to achieve that ?

Comment: What platform? What language?

Comment: @Anton : the platform is j2me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use below method to convert the `com.sun.lwuit.Image` to byte[].

```
public byte[] imageProcessing(String imageName, Image image) {

        int[] rgb = image.getRGB();
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(baos);
        dos.writeUTF(imageName);

        for (int i = 0; i < rgb.length; i++) {
            dos.writeInt(rgb[i]);
        }

   return baos.toByteArray();
 }
```

Comment: is it possible to use the InputStream obtained from the FileConnection of the filename of the Image ? Because there is the read method in the InputStream javaDoc , and the read method has a byte[] parameter which will contain the byte[] value of the Image ?

Comment: When I try to create an Image from this byteArray, I get an IllegalArgumentException.